# conversion from ddmmyyyy to mmddyyy

Tags: c#, datetime

This is giving an exception:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff";
string dt_db1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtTenureFrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
   .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(dt_db1, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: What culture is your machine running in?

Comment: That's an aweful lot of parsing and reparsing. But what input string are you starting with?  What is the value in the `txtTenureFrom` textbox?

Comment: Have you tried splitting the statement into sections to see what the `ParseExact` returned before you try to convert it to a string again.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the input data, but the first part looks inconsistent with the second.

1. You start with a date value you expect to be in `dd/MM/yyyy` format, without a time component.
2. You convert it to a date value in `MM/dd/yyyy` format, still without out a time component.
3. You then try to parse it *again* in `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff` format, expecting a time component to somehow be introduced in the string???

Where do you expect the time to magically come from?